# Head(int main) not being updated after reversing the linked list

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

I have the following code

```
node* reverse_ll_recr(node* head)
{
if(head->next == NULL) return head;
reverse_ll_recr(head->next);
head->next->next = head;
head->next = NULL;
}
```

And in main i call it with

```
head = reverse_ll_recr(head);
```

Problem is that head is not updated and would only print the last element since it is pointing to NULL after reversal. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Dry run your code on a couple of sample lists. That'll help you figure out the problem.

Comment: You think maybe your function should return a value? After all, you have `head = reverse_ll_recr(head);`. If the function doesn't return a value, what value do you think will be assigned to `head`?